# Regex pattern matching yields false

Tags: java, regex

I have executed the code below, but its result is false. Is my pattern is correct? What is wrong here? If I am wrong please correct me because I am stuck on this.

```
String name = "] RESPONSE GET - 192.168.200.121 -";
string pat = "] RESPONSE (GET|GETNEXT|GETBULK|SET|TRAP) - ^192\\.168\\.200\\.121$ -";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pat);
Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
System.out.println(m.find());
```

Comment: You have the `^` and `$` characters - indicating start of string and end of string respectively - in the middle of your pattern. That's never going to work. What are you actually trying to do with the IP address here?

Comment: how could it start with `] RESPONSE...` and start also with `192\\.`? Remove the `^` and `$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
] RESPONSE (GET|GETNEXT|GETBULK|SET|TRAP) - 192\\.168\\.200\\.121 -
```

You had the `^` and `$` characters in the middle of your string. Those represent the start and end of the string to match, respectively. The start / end of a string can't be in the middle of a string, obviously ;-)